# How to align VrVideoView head direction with reality

Tags: android, google-vr

I have a 360° video. I want my users to play it from exactly the same place the video was taken. I need to align the head direction of the video being played with real direction of the device based on compass sensor. In short - if device is pointing to north I want the video being played to show north.

I am looking at Google VR's VRVideoView but this widget always starts playing in the same direction regardless if my device is pointing north or south.

Maybe Google VR is a blind path? Please suggest what would you use.
Thanks!

Comment: Have you found a solution to this problem?

Comment: not satisfied yet.first option I found is to hack the initial VrVideoView head angle by dispatching touch events - this is ugly but working.

The second option is to try more complex (and I hope more customizable) widgets. This seems promissing: https://developers.google.com/vr/android/samples/video360

Comment: Could you please provide an example how you dispatch these touch events? I already tried this, but couldn't achieve any movement of the screen. I would really appreciate it!

Comment: well to hack it using motion events is certainly not correct solution, but if it will help you here you are. You have to simulate 3 motionevents using videoWidgetView.dispatchTouchEvent(): ACTION_DOWN (at the center of screen), ACTION_MOVE (center screen shifted to the right), ACTION_UP (center screen shifted to the right). I placed the shifting logic into VrVideoEventListener#onLoadSuccess. I tried it with gorillas VrVideoView sample and it worked - the initial angle was shifted. What's left to do is to convert video-sensor difference angle to motion pixels and this can be tricky :)